# HTML Body is overflown

Tags: html, css, video

I'm trying to create a website where the first part is a video, on top of it is a navigation bar and description sentence. The second part is a div with a picture and a lorem ipsum paragraph. But the two-part is mushed together. Do you know why?

The first part is the video-container div. It contains a video, a navigation bar and some introductory words

The second part is the intro div which has an image and a paragraph side by side

```
<style>
        html, 
        body {
            border: 1px solid blue;
            min-height:100%; 
            padding:0; 
            margin:0;}

        * {
            font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            margin-top: -5px;
        }
        .nav {
            border: 1px solid red;
            margin-right: 30px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .nav li {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .nav li a {
            text-decoration: none;
            font-size: 23px;
            font-weight: 600;
            color: #C71585;
            letter-spacing: 0.03em;
        }
        .nav img {
            width: 150px;
        }
        video { 
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            object-fit: cover;
            background-size: cover;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            z-index: -1;
            box-sizing: content-box;
        }
        .video-container {
            position: relative;
            height: 100%;
            border: 1px solid yellow;
        }
        .content {
            border: 1px solid yellow;
            position: absolute;
            left: 50px;
            top: 150px;
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 5px 20px;
            font-size: 20px;
            overflow: none;
        }
        .content h1 {
            font-size: 100px;
            color:  #C71585;
        }
        #myBtn {
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-top: 40px;
            border: 1px solid #C71585;
            font-size: 26px;
            font-weight: 800;
            color: #e827a0;
            padding: 15px 60px;
            background-color: transparent;
            transition: 0.2s ease-in;
        }
        #myBtn:hover {
            background-color: rgba(199, 21, 133);
            color: white;
        }
        .intro {
            overflow: none;
            margin-top: 30px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-around;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .intro img {
            width: 500px;
        }
        .intro-text {
            width: 30%;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>




        <div class="video-container"> 
                <video autoplay muted loop id="video">
                        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            <div class="nav">
                <img src="logo.png" alt="logo">
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">My resume</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <h1>Avid learner and</h1>
                <h1>Constant striver</h1>
                <button id="myBtn">Who am I</button>
            </div>

        </div>

    <div class='intro'>
        <img src="01.jpeg" alt="">
        <div class="intro-text">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In pellentesque ex a felis laoreet, ut bibendum sem eleifend. Quisque egestas sem sed velit molestie tincidunt. Phasellus at pellentesque odio. Phasellus sem leo, hendrerit et massa vehicula, iaculis cursus erat. Vestibulum et viverra nisi, sit amet condimentum sem. Duis gravida faucibus nisl nec pharetra. Curabitur convallis risus enim, nec semper lorem cursus varius. Quisque feugiat vitae dui non ultricies. Integer ipsum quam, dictum et quam nec, imperdiet euismod nulla. Nam bibendum sagittis orci, eget tincidunt risus luctus nec. Quisque lacus urna, tincidunt vel lobortis in, suscipit sit amet nunc. Fusce ultrices erat a nunc dignissim hendrerit. Maecenas sed pharetra quam, vitae suscipit nunc. Aenean molestie dui aliquet augue eleifend, quis congue ligula laoreet. Ut quis est pellentesque, fringilla odio ac, tincidunt nibh.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of css flex property, in your case please add

```
.flex-container {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

under your style tags and assign this class to `intro` class div as `<div class='intro flex-container'>`, will this worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

you can easily wrap the .video-container and .intro divs with a div tag and give it style display flex and make sure you add flex wrap also.
Then just give your video and intro containers width 100%